# How to make user to believe that they have visited the best site?

Tags: website-design

I've a website. But, my question is how to make a user believe that a user has visited the best site ever?

What could be added to a existing site that user might think that, this webisite is good.

Comment: what about giving the user the best site ever instead of tricking him?. I think that you should rephrase your question and explain better what do you want, because right doesn't sound very good.

Comment: This reads a bit like SPAM to me. But in case it isn't, the answer is: animated GIFs of kittens.

Comment: Subliminal messages, hypnosis, or just build the best site ever as Derek suggested. The "best" is subjective - some people may think *facebook* is the best - I hate it. Of course animated kittens never fail.

Comment: Animated wallpapers, animated flaming skulls, and a midi that automatically plays in the background when the page load all indicate that you are on the cutting edge of web design.  Also, frames indicate that you are a skilled developer who can grasp the more difficult concepts of HTML

Comment: Can confirm what @rotard. Made a site using those principles in '92, got all the girls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: Build the best site ever.